# Transistor latch circuit stays on and button is unresponsive

Tags: transistors, latch

[image: schematic][image: latch switch on][image: latch switch off]I'm using a 2n2222a and 2n3906 with a 2n3906 as a reset and a irf4905 mosfet to carry the load I've redone this circuit many times on the computer, and breadboard and it seems to work but as soon as I assemble it the button is unresponsive and the mosfet stays on I thought maybe the soldering iron might be frying the transistors so I put them separately on a breadboard last to help prevent any stray voltage and the mosfet stays on I'll try uploading pictures of it soon

Comment: Please add a schematic diagram - it is hard to figure out the circuit from the simulated  breadboard photos.

Comment: This is difficult to do without reference designators.  If the lower left transistor is supposed to be NPN (the arrow looks strange), then the circuit as shown at this time cannot work.

Comment: And neither side of the battery is connected to GND.  Also, where is the "load" connected?

Comment: The battery is connected any voltage 6-13 volts will work depending on the voltage of the diode on the drain pin of the mosfet and the pnp is only to add a reset pin its supposed to turn on and not let you turn it off until the capacitor reaches the same voltage as the output after the diode

Comment: And yes the left transistor is a npn